# How to convert 12 V DC to 19 V DC with minimal energy losses

Tags: power-supply, power

How can I convert 12 V DC to 19 V DC so my laptop can operate from an 12 V solar battery?

Comment: Impossible without energy loss.

Comment: Get the most efficient boost converter you can afford, it won't be lossless but as Andy aka said, that's just not possible.

Comment: ata kama itakuwa na energy losses what I gonna do to solve this...because my power inverter is draining the battery very fast...

Comment: I've often connected my 19V HP laptops directly to 12 volts. Both show about 60% battery, not charging, not draining. Works ok for me.

Comment: ata yngu n 19v HP if wire directly to the battery will it operate

Comment: **Don't** directly connect 12 V to the battery contacts unless you want the battery to catch fire or explode. I suggest you get a **laptop car adapter** these make 19 V from 12 V. Yes in theory the laptop can work directly from 12 V but to make that work in practice is a challenge.

Comment: poa what does it cost

Comment: 19V feeds to DC-DC subsystems,. One for the charger and 12 will be insufficent and one for the MOBO multple outputs, wher 12V  should be more than adequate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are DC/DC converters that have a 75-98% efficiency, ref.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC-to-DC_converter

So "No energy loss" is a goal that can't be reached!

But with a god DC/DC converter the losses will be neglect able.

Comment: I want someone to help me  make one for myself

Comment: @FrankTaffas MatsK just did. Go to the website he gave you and study and understand what that does and then apply that knowledge in your own implementation.